# How to Update Offline db based on update from online db only

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, api, synchronization

i need your help. I have an android project. In this project i have to sync the db online and offline. For the offline db, i'm using sqlite and mysql for my online db. To retrieve data i'm using api. Now the question is, how can i update my offline when there's update in my online db ? I just want to update the updated data from my online db only not replacing all data in my sqlite. I'm using android studio. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to use last modified date on both end. With that you get new updated data from the the server based on the last modified date.

Comment: You should check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580240/android-update-client-sqlite-database-using-gcm

Comment: you could also used realtime database that would update data once the device is online or the data is being altered example is the firebase realtime database

Comment: if i change only one line in my online db, can i update only one line to in my offline db? @Nas

Comment: @androidnoobdev

Comment: @NickyApriliani That depends upon your update script. if your online db can send only one record at the time of update db call you can do. so you have to make that script such powerful.

Comment: You should use `Sync Adapter` where you can find many training material online such as [this](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html).